# postgres streaming replication slave ignores zero_damaged_pages

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have:

> ```
> 2017-04-19 09:33:26 UTC  :: WARNING:  page 43087 of relation base/11137505/11139144 is uninitialized
> 2017-04-19 09:33:26 UTC  :: CONTEXT:  xlog redo visible: rel 1663/11137505/11139144; blk 43087
> 2017-04-19 09:33:26 UTC  :: PANIC:  WAL contains references to invalid pages
> 2017-04-19 09:33:26 UTC  :: CONTEXT:  xlog redo visible: rel 1663/11137505/11139144; blk 43087
> ```

on 3 out of 7 slaves in replication on 9.3.9

The database 11137505 is not important for prod, so I decided to try using a broken db while building up a new slave and so [I try to](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-developer.html) `zero_damaged_pages = on` to see what else is broken.

Yet it seems to ignore the setting appended to the end of the `postgres.conf`, producing the same log and terminating the instance.

This option is not meant for such usage - right? I can't make replicated slave to zero the corrupted page and go on replaying?